# Make a block from a "part" of a drop down menu

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

I have a D7 site with a drop down menu at the top, the second item across the top is "About Us".  Presently it looks like this, see attached pic.

[image: Screen capture of my present menu]

I want the "contents" of this part of the menu to be a "BLOCK" that I can display on several pages.  How can I do that?

In Drupal menus, the arrangement looks like this, see attached pic:

[image: Screen capture of the menu arrangement in Drupal menus]

The menu item "about us" has a URL of "about-us".  I'd like the content of this to show up in a sidebar that I could drop in perhaps as a block or other method.  How can I make a block out of just a "section" of a menu, and yet have this as dynamic content?  I want the users to be able to edit the list of menu links included in "about-us" but not have to manually put the contents of the new links into the sidebar.  I'm thinking of maybe a "view" but I've never made a view of a menu before.

Thanks for the help.

Dave N

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using menu block (https://drupal.org/project/menu_block), which allows blocks to be created from menus. The most important part would probably be starting level and max depth, which allows you to specify the options you'd like to use.

If you'd like an example usage similar to what you're attempting to achieve, just let me know and I'll take some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, maybe just direct to a page on the web that's actually using it if possible, no need for screen shots.  Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, just install the module, and go to your Blocks administration panel. From there, you'll see 'Create menu block', and it's all pretty self explanatory at that point. I'd experiment a bit to see some of the options, but one of its major features is the 'partial menu' you're looking for. Good luck!